# Flake ID implementation in Go

Tags: go

I have created an implementation in GO for generating Flake ids. The implementation in based on [Factual\Skuld's implementation in Clojure](https://github.com/Factual/skuld/blob/master/src/skuld/flake.clj)

Current limitations include:

The current implementation does not store last timestamp in a persistent store. This means that in case the process hosting flake is stopped, the system time of the node hosting the flake process is moved back. Then the current flake implementation will generate an ID that has a timestamp that has been used as part of an earlier ID.

[Github Repo](https://github.com/nmjmdr/goflake)

```
    package flake

import (
    "encoding/binary"
    "errors"
    "macNodeId"
    "math"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

//
// Acknowledgement: Based on Factual\Skuld's implementation of Flake Id
// 160 bit flake id

/*
  [64 bits | Timestamp, in milliseconds since the epoch]
  [32 bits | a per-process counter]
  [48 bits | a host identifier]
  [16 bits | the process ID]
*/

/* follows a big endian approach to the id */
/* this means:
64 --> byte[0] to byte[7](inclusive)
32 --> byte[8] to byte [11](inclusive)
48 --> byte[12] byte[17](inclusive)
16 --> byte[18] to byte[19](inclusive)
*/

// Consider the time to start from year 2010
// time.Date(2010, time.January, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
const epoch int64 = 1262304000000000000
const maxCounter = math.MaxUint32

// node id length is 6 bytes
const nodeIdLength = 6

var mutex = &sync.Mutex{}
var lastNow int64
var counter uint32
var nodeId []byte
var initialized bool
var initMutex = &sync.Mutex{}

/*
 Process Id related assumptions:
 the assumption here is that process ids will not execced int16
 that is max: 65535
 but they can, check: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/02/05/10495426.aspx

 code might generate overallping process ids, if process ids get larger than: 65535
 also it is assumed that process ids cannot be negative
*/

type flk struct {
}

type NodeId interface {
    // a 48 byte node id
    Id() ([]byte, error)
}

func FlakeNode(nId NodeId) (*flk, error) {
    initMutex.Lock()
    defer initMutex.Unlock()
    var err error
    if !initialized {
        nodeId, err = nId.Id()
        initialized = true
    }
    return new(flk), err
}

func FlakeNodeWithMacId() (*flk, error) {

    macId := new(macNodeId.MacNodeId)
    f, err := FlakeNode(macId)

    return f, err
}

func (f *flk) NextId() ([]byte, error) {

    b := make([]byte, 20)

    //copy the timestamp
    now := time.Now().UnixNano()
    if now < lastNow {
        // time has moved backwards, this could lead to issues, error out
        return nil, errors.New("Time has moved back, cannot proceed further")
    }

    lastTs := (lastNow - epoch) / 1000000
    ts := (now - epoch) / 1000000

    mutex.Lock()
    // this is an edge case: in case there have been equal or more calls
    // than 2^32, then we need to wait until we move to next timestamp
    // is the counter nearing a reset to zero?
    // and if our lastTs the same as current ts?
    if (counter == maxCounter) && (ts <= lastTs) {
        // then we need wait until ts is greater than
        // lastTs - so that we do not end up repeatingids for the current node
        for ts <= lastTs {
            now = time.Now().UnixNano()
            ts = (now - epoch) / 1000000
        }
    }

    binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(b[0:8], uint64(ts))

    //increment the counter and assign to bytes
    // has time moved since the last call?
    if lastTs < ts {
        // reset the counter
        counter = 0
    } // if the time has not moved since the last call, we just increment
    // the counter

    counter++
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint32(b[8:12], counter)

    // save the lastnow to a file (to be done)
    // so that we can determine if time has moved back
    // frequently store lastNow to a file
    // to ensure time cannot move back
    lastNow = now

    mutex.Unlock()

    //copy the host id or node id
    copy(b[12:(12+nodeIdLength)], nodeId)

    //copy the process id
    pid := uint16(os.Getpid())
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint16(b[18:20], pid)
    return b, nil
}
```

`MacNodeId` implements `NodeId` interface and generates a node ID based on the MAC address:

```
package macNodeId

import (
    "net"
    "bytes"
    "crypto/sha1"
    "errors"
)

// node id length is 6 bytes
const nodeIdLength = 6

type MacNodeId struct {
}

func (n *MacNodeId) Id() ([]byte,error) {

    macNodeId := make([]byte,nodeIdLength)
    err := assignMacNodeId(&macNodeId)

    return macNodeId,err 
}


func assignMacNodeId(ptrId *[]byte) error {
    inets,err := net.Interfaces()

    if err != nil {
        return errors.New("Unable to obtain mac address: "+err.Error())
    }
        macs := make([][]byte,len(inets))
    for i:=0;i<len(inets);i++ {
        macs[i] = inets[i].HardwareAddr
    }
    m := bytes.Join(macs,nil)
    s :=  sha1.Sum(m)
    copy((*ptrId),s[0:nodeIdLength])
    return nil
}
```

Comment: "Every time you write a comment, you should grimace and feel the failure of your ability of expression." Robert C. Martin ;)